# SMTPHandler in Python's logging module sending emails one at a time. How can I stop this?

Tags: python, logging

I'm attempting to use Python's `logging` module to send emails containing logs.  The problem that I'm having is that each time I write a log entry, an email is sent.  How do I queue the log messages and send a single email at the conclusion of the script?

I have a feeling that it's done with the `emit()` method, but I can't figure out how to use it.

```
import logging, logging.handlers
log = logging.getLogger("mylogger")
log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
h2 = logging.handlers.SMTPHandler(mailhost='mailserver',
                            fromaddr='noreply@example.com',
                            toaddrs=['me@example.com'],
                            subject='The log',
                            credentials=('user','pwd'),
                            secure=None)
h2.setLevel(logging.INFO)
h2.setFormatter(f)
log.addHandler(h2)

log.info("Did something")
log.info("Did something else")
log.info("This would send a third email. :-(")
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1610845/how-to-collate-output-in-python-logging-memoryhandler-smtphandler/1611958#1611958) which I gave for a similar question. An example handler to use is [here](https://gist.github.com/1379446); you can adapt it to your requirements.

Comment: @VinaySajip - what are your thoughts on using the smtplib module to send emails instead?

Comment: @algotr8der - You can see from the example handler that it actually uses `smtplib` to send the emails.

Comment: Just giving a link is not a good answer.

Comment: @rhermans It's fine when it's a link to Stack Overflow itself.

Answer (score 2):

Simply subclass SMTPHandler in order to produce the wanted behavior.
you could for example override the emit method in order to send a mail on every third logged message

Caution: Depending on the implementation you chose no mail at all would be sent if you do log only one or two times. Perhaps a delayed sending could be the solution: Wait a second before you send the mail. If after a second no other line is received, then send it else add the line to the message to be send and wait another second ... and so on... (Delayed sending must be done in a separate thread (consider using [Timer](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/threading.html?highlight=threading.timer#threading.Timer))